# Can not find dnsspoof in Kali

Tags: software-installation, kali-linux

I am using the latest Kali distribution. I understood  there supposed to be an application called `dnsspoof`. Where should it be?

[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2]

Comment: What version of Kali are you using? (Be specific, please; "the latest" is not specific.) Don't forget to add this to your question. Don't put it here in the comments.

Comment: "new with Linux" and "using the latest Kali" does not seem a good idea

Answer (score 5):

You are not finding `dnsspoof` because it is part of the `dsniff` package.

To install it do in the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install dsniff
```

Also `dnsspoof` is not a graphical application. You are supposed to use it from the command line.